# If $G$ is an infinite group, what can you say about the number of elements of order $n$ in the group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

I just started with group theory. I know that for any finite group $G$, the number of elements of order $n$ in group $G$ will be multiple of $\phi(n)$ where $\phi$ is the Euler phi function. But what can I conclude about the number of elements of order $n$ when $G$ is infinite? Is there a relation with the theorem of finite groups?

Comment: Your question doesn't match your title. Also, you need to provide more context. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: You can conclude that $G$ is infinite

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540461/number-of-elements-of-order-n-in-an-infinite-group

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, without knowing more about the group. $(\mathbb Z, +)$ has no such elements, for example.

Comment: Well, but $0$ is a multiple of $\phi(8)$...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes but $0$ does not have order $8$. It has order $1$.

Comment: So? How many elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ have order $8$? Answer: zero. Is the number of elements of order $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ a multiple of $\phi(8)$? Answer: yes.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh wotever

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But how can I show this is true when $G$ is infinite?

Comment: The statement in question is "The number of elements of order $n$ in a finite group $G$ is a multiple of $\phi(n)$." That statement is true in $\mathbb{Z}$ for any $n$, so your example does not seem to address the question at all. In fact, there are finite groups where the answer is likewise "zero".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I realize my question is badly formed, so I changed my question. Is the number of elements of order $n$ in an infinite group $G$ still a multiple of $\phi$$(n)$?

Comment: @Victor: Please don't hijack a comment thread in someone's answer to re-ask the question that was closed, in an attempt to circumvent that closure.